# Mutually referencing two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Out of curiousity;

If I've got two tables, A and B;

```
A
ID int (PK)
B_ID int (FK)

B
ID int (PK)
A_ID int (FK)
```

A has a reference to B. B has a reference to A. A_ID and B_ID are non-nullable.

How can I add rows to these tables? I can't add a row to A without adding a row to B, nor vice versa, however if the tables contained this data;

```
A
ID   B_ID
1    100

B
ID   A_ID
100  1
```

Then obviously that is fine. If I wanted to insert this data, would I have to first disable data integrity or can I somehow add these two rows at once?

Thanks, and apologies for the title - I've no idea what this is called, or I'd look it up myself.

Comment: I might call this "circular referential integrity." What is the purpose of the FK pointing in BOTH directions?

Comment: It could be used to enforce a one-to-one relationship for example. As I said, it's more just curiosity to see if it's doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a well explained article on msdn:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/01/10033575.aspx

and another one on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference

Take a look at both and read them carefully.

Hope it helps you.

Cheers

Comment: Marked as answer since it at least gave me the correct term. Thanks.